# Android onDrag How to change moving view's background when moving

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using relative layout for purpose. I need to change background image when moving image, moved to a particular position. but i can't access moving view and change background when layout moving(dragging).

Thanks.

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                //come here when moving view
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                owner.removeView(view);
                RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for that,

```
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            ((RelativeLayout) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            break;
```

and ACTION_DROP you can change again if you want.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply.i tried this code. but didn't changed the dragging layout background. changed parent view background to red.

Comment: so change the view by another what you need to change background color

Comment: its only change when i drop the view.i need to change the view background when i dragging it. can I do it?

Comment: this code changes the layout that is still on the screen but does not change the copy of that layout that is being dragged.